# How to Handle Gunicorn Error on GAE deployment

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a python service on GAE, and when I deploy it I get the following error [Error on GAE logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3JdR.png)

I have not added Gunicorn in my requirements.txt file but when I debug my service on GAE, I see its there in the Requirement file.

Can someone help figure out what's wrong.
I just have a main.py in my service, and here's the Yaml I am using

```
service: service
runtime: python37
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

# [START handlers]
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Requirement.txt file

```
Flask==1.0.4
Werkzeug>=0.14
google-cloud-pubsub==0.37.2
```

Main.py

```
import logging
import os
import time
import sys
import json

# [START imports]
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from google.cloud import pubsub

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/publish', methods=['POST'])
def form():
    data = request.json

    if data:
       return jsonify({"message": "DONE"})
    else:
       return "Hello World"
```

Comment: Can you add the whole traceback, not just a fragment of the last line as a picture, please? Is it AppEngine Standard or Flexible?

Comment: The Image posted was the very first lines of logs after hitting the endpoint, and its AppEngine Standard

Comment: how does your `main.py` look like?

Comment: Added Main.py in the above description @yedpodtrzitko

Comment: Thanks. No idea, the incomplete traceback baffles me. Maybe try to setup logging client https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python  if it will improve it? Also why pubsub `0.37.2`, that's several years old...

Comment: Is that the complete `main.py` file? I tried deploying what you provided but it fails unless I add an `app.run` instruction.

Comment: I didn't add app.run but was working fine for me

Comment: And does it work now after adding it?

Comment: There should be more to the traceback. You can click it in the logs to expand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding dependency six in requirements.txt solved the problem for me.

```
 six==1.14.0
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with the exact line that solved the issue?

Comment: Do not forget to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) when you are done.

Comment: Please update your answer to provide the full solution of the problem, as it may be helpful for somebody else facing the same problem.